# SQL Server 2008 Collation conflict - how to resolve?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

For simplification, POC, I have the following query, using character typed columns:

```
select AH_NAME1 from GGIMAIN.SYSADM.BW_AUFTR_KOPF
union
select AH_NAME1 from GGI2014.SYSADM.BW_AUFTR_KOPF
```

and I get the following error:

> Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 2
>   Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CS_AS" in the UNION operation.

`GGI2014` was indeed created with collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. This has been changed in SMS and the instance has been restarted, also in SMS.

When I look in SMS, as well as query:

```
select name, collation_name from sys.databases
```

all indications are that both `GGIMAIN` and `GGI2014` are collated `Latin1_General_CS_AS`.

Does anyone have any advice on what else needs to be done?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: Hi marc_s.  Can you explain why you edited my post?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
select AH_NAME1 COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT from GGIMAIN.SYSADM.BW_AUFTR_KOPF
union
select AH_NAME1 COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT from GGI2014.SYSADM.BW_AUFTR_KOPF
```

Unless I am mistaken, changing the collation of the database does not change the collation of the already existing objects. Only new objects will be affected

Comment: Please note that if there is an AS keyword in the select statement, the COLLATE goes in before it.

Comment: @SteveTaylor Thanks a lot, that's saved me alot

Answer (score 2):

Try this one (maybe you're columns have different collation) -

```
SELECT AH_NAME1 COLLATE database_default
FROM GGIMAIN.SYSADM.BW_AUFTR_KOPF

UNION

SELECT AH_NAME1 COLLATE database_default
FROM GGI2014.SYSADM.BW_AUFTR_KOPF
```

Answer (score 0):

I add a collate for each field of the query

```
SELECT Field1 collate default_database
,field2 collate default_database
,fieldn collate default_database
From DB1.dbo.table_x
UNION ALL
SELECT Field1 collate default_database
,field2 collate default_database
,fieldn collate default_database
From DB2.dbo.table_y
```

**PD.only in the query that gives the error**

I hope it works and I got them out of trouble