# PHP: SQL Syntax error on equivalent server

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, apache

Our development and production servers are identical, except by capacity (RAM, Disk, and so on): MS Win Server 2008 R2 Ent/MS SQL Server 2005/Apache2.2/PHP 5.213. In our dev machine the following (summarized) sql works perfectly:

```
SELECT somecol collate database_default 
FROM localtable
UNION
SELECT somecol collate database_default 
FROM linkedserver.remotedb.dbo.table
```

*Note: The linked server is the same one in both dev/prod servers.*

In the **prod** server it gives the following error:

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax
>   near 'DATABASE_DEFAULT'.

If I remove the collate dabatase_default clauses, I get this error (as expected):

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Cannot resolve
>   the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI" and
>   "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the UNION operation.

If if point the prod code to the dev database, it works. On the other hand, if I point de dev code to the prod database, it fails.

What on earth is going on?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 Collation conflict - how to resolve?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21433204/sql-server-2008-collation-conflict-how-to-resolve)

Comment: you mean this: `extension=php_mssql.dll`?

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate because it's note the same error. My problem is the syntax error, which should not occur. If I run the query in the Management Studio it runs smoothly.

Comment: you mean to say that if you connect to your prod and run the above  using management studio, it works?

Answer (score 0):

I belive you have diffrent default collations on servers and it couse the problem.

```
select somecol collate database_default from localtable
union
select somecol collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS from linkedserver.remotedb.dbo.table
```

Please post what collation is on columns.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all who tried to help.

It was our fault: we were connecting to a third database with compatibility level set to 70. So, SQL Server was interpreting the query under this setting. We switched the compatibility level to 80 and it works as expected.

It's interesting to note that the compatibility level of the databased involved in the query are irrelevant. SQL Server regards the level of the database you are connected to.